# Coded on Windows, Not working on Linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, curl

I'm having issues with my code on Linux, It works fine on Windows which is running PHP 7.1 and Linux is running PHP 7.0. Looking at my code it doesn't look like I am using any of the features that came in 7.1 and are not in 7.0.

If I call this method on its own it works fine, When it is used within my other code it doesn't seem to run at all.

```
public function titleRegex($title){
    $re = "/^.+?(?=\\s*[(.]?(\\d{4}))/mi";
    $str = "$title";

    if(preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches) != null) {

        if (!empty($matches[0])) {

            $arrayString =  implode('', $matches[0]);

            return $arrayString;
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
```

---

```
 $title = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
 $regexTitle = $this->titleRegex($title);
 $imdbQuery = $this->imdbScraper($regexTitle);
 $location = base64_encode(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
 // SQL Data is here
```

When I run the directoryscanner it attempts no regex, If I call the regex method on its own and pass my own values into it, It works fine. Also I have installed PHP7.0-curl and when I do a curl request on all the movie titles it returns nothing... but if I call the method on its own it works fine. I am totally lost what could be causing this.

Comment: windows uses \ for path while linux uses / . simply make your regex match on / and it should work.

Comment: What is `\\s` and `\\d`?

Comment: Use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: @Dimi Awesome, I admit I did copy and paste that Regex from somewhere else and didn't know that was looking for file paths. It's strange that my curl requests within my code are not working though.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I am not sure, I got this off someone else.

Comment: @NathanK as AbraCadaver suggested, you should still try to use pre-defined constants to make your projects compatibale with everything. http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

Comment: Thank you guys! It turns out I wasn't calling it for extension .mp4, I am an idiot but in the process I now use DIRECTORY_SEPERATORs